# Ruby on Rails. How to show record only once?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I want to know how to show a record only exactly after it was created. So i want to show it only once.

Just see. I have model called Claim. User creates new Claim (user is anonymous). I want to show this Claim only ofter user creates it and never again. How can I do it?

I think that I can use flash hash, but i think it is not enough secure to create symbols from user data.

Comment: Why don't you delete it after you view it?

Answer (score 1):

You could have a `viewed` attribute on your model that you set to true in the show action. If `viewed` is true then skip rendering the view.

```
unless thingy.viewed 
  thingy.viewed = true
  thingy.save

  render like normal...
end
```

Comment: I would go with this. Seems like a pretty solid solution.

Comment: Oh, I must note that I would use update_attribute(:viewed, true) rather than setter than save though.

Comment: Ok, but maybe somebody will add solution, that will not use database column?