# Rendering a layout if it doesn't exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I render a layout only one time if it is calling two times? 
Is there any way to check if layout exist?

```
 <%= render partial:'layouts/test' %>
```

Answer (score 0):

For first question these two SO posts can help

[Rails: allowing a partial to only be rendered once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7690727/rails-allowing-a-partial-to-only-be-rendered-once)

[Ruby on Rails. How to show record only once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1865110/ruby-on-rails-how-to-show-record-only-once)

---

For second question you can use [template_exists?](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/LookupContext/ViewPaths/template_exists%3F) like this to check out if it's exists or not.

```rb
lookup_context.template_exists?("test", "layouts", true)
```